# Website can not access MongoDB on AWS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services

I've deployed MEAN Stack website on AWS. And website runs well on my local.
But it shows POST/xxx/register 500(Internal Server Error) after deploying it, when I am trying to access DB(MongoDB).

I've deployed this like below flow.

- Project Published Github
- Installed instance on AWS by using MEAN powered Bitnami.
- Added protocols for website and mongoDB (8080, 27017).
- Cloned from Git by using Putty.

And it seems that DB access problem.
For example, when I've tired to register a user on live server Putty shows like below

> POST /api/v1/register 500 35.645 ms - 1675

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var https = require('https');


var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passport = require('passport');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/news');
require('./models/Users');
require('./config/passport');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var authenticate_api = require('./routes/authenticate_api');

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/api/v1/', authenticate_api);
```

and the route/authenticate_api.js file

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passport = require('passport');
var User = mongoose.model('User');

require('../config/passport');
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();


var jwt = require('express-jwt');
var auth = jwt({secret: 'SECRET', userProperty: 'payload'});

router.post('/register', function(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.body.username || !req.body.password) {
        return res.status(400).json({message: 'Please fill out all fields'});
    }
    var user = new User();
    user.username = req.body.username;
    user.setPassword(req.body.password);
    user.save(function(err, user) {
        if(err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        return res.json({token: user.generateJWT()});
    });
})

module.exports = router;
```

What's the matter with that?
Cheers.

Comment: Loads of code that does not matter to the problem here. The error is in the code you are not showing. `./routes/authenticate_api`

Comment: I'm asking you to include it in your question since the error is occurring on the route which is being defined inside that code. I'm also saying that none of the code you did list in your question has anything to do with the error. Simply supply the code for the route which is affected.

Comment: You mean, you wanna checkout authenticate_api.js file?

Comment: I mean its the **only** code you actually need to post on this question. Please edit your question to at least include it.

Comment: Edited it. it's okay?

Comment: `var user = new User();` There is no import of `User` in scope.

Comment: It's my mistake and I didn't copy the codes. But remember, project works well on my local. You didn't read my question carefully. How can the project work well without importing of User in scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just solved it myself.
It was a mongoDB permission problem
I could find out mongodb status always stop/waiting.
So I solved it like below.

```
/var/log/mongodb/  sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb .
/var/lib/mongodb/  sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb .
/stack/mongodb/tmp/   sudo chown mongodb mongodb-27017.sock
$/ ps -ef | grep mongo      {get for mongo PID}
$/ kill -9 PID
$/ sudo service mongodb start
```

It works well now. Thanks for your consideration.